# Odoo 11 - Missing <!DOCTYPE html> in website page

Tags: html, odoo, doctype, odoo-11

I noticed that in some page of my website, implemented with Odoo 11, the `<!DOCTYPE html`> is missing.

This is probably main cause of an issue linked to the product table in the shop.

I checked the "web.layout" view and the code is there:

```
<t name="Web layout" t-name="web.layout">&lt;!DOCTYPE html&gt;
```

But the property is not shown if I check the source code of the "shop" page, it is only shown if I login as administrator to the site.

Any suggestion on how to fix the issue?

Comment: I had something similar, It was the translation check it

Comment: Thank you for the response, can you please explain better where to check and what in the translation?

Thanks,

Comment: Go to technical menu terms, search for term with source contains DOCTYPE and keep the translation value the same

Comment: The tranlation is correct, in both language the string is the same, the issue is that the <!DOCTYPE html> is missing if the user is not logged in...

Comment: Mmm you have created [this issue](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/issues/44612), right? Could you show us how you have deployed Odoo in more detail? If not, you can try with other inverse proxy such as NginX and check if the result is the same

Comment: @ChesuCR Yes I've created the issue, I solved the issue removing add on website_lazy_load... now the speed index is decreased, but the rendering of the website is correct. I have to debug the add on to try to solve the issue.